# "invalid new-expression of abstract class type" problem with unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, unique-ptr

I am developing a class system to be able to compare data but but there are some error due to unique_ptr that i don't understand.

I believe this is mainly because of the pure virtual clone method of "**Valeur**"

**Valeur.hh** :

```
#pragma once
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

namespace common {

    class Valeur {
    public:
        //virtual bool operator==(Valeur const& v) const = 0;
        virtual std::unique_ptr<Valeur> clone() const = 0;
    };

    class Objet : public Valeur{
    private:
        std::map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<Valeur>> _valeurs;
        bool contientValeur(std::string key,Valeur const& Valeur)const;
    public:
        Objet() = default;
        Objet( Objet const& o);
        void ajouterValeur(std::string key,std::unique_ptr<Valeur> v);
        std::unique_ptr<Valeur> clone () const override;
    };
   
    class Boolleen : public Valeur { //problem
    private:
        bool _b;
    public:
        Boolleen (bool const& b);
        std::unique_ptr<Valeur> clone () const override = 0;
    };

    class Null : public Valeur { // problem
    public :
       
        std::unique_ptr<Valeur> clone () const override;
    };



}
```

**Valeur.cc**:
the error says : *"invalid new-expression of abstract class type‘ common :: Boolleen "*
however none of the classes are abstract

```
#include "Valeur.hh"
using namespace common;
bool Objet::contientValeur(std::string key, const Valeur &v) const {
    auto cherch = _valeurs.find(key);
    if(cherch == _valeurs.end()) return false;
    else if (cherch->second->operator==(v)) return true;
    return false;
}

Objet::Objet(const Objet &o)
{
    for ( auto const& e : o._valeurs)
    {
        _valeurs.clear();
       _valeurs.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::unique_ptr<Valeur>>(e.first,e.second->clone()));

    }
}

void Objet::ajouterValeur(std::string key,std::unique_ptr<Valeur> v)
{
    auto cherch = _valeurs.find(key);
    if(cherch == _valeurs.end()) {
        _valeurs[key] = std::move(v);
    }
    else return throw "Erreur : ajout de clé multiple";
}

std::unique_ptr<Valeur> Objet::clone() const
{
    return std::make_unique<Objet>(*this);
}
Boolleen::Boolleen(const bool &b) : _b(b) {}

std::unique_ptr<Valeur> Boolleen::clone() const
{
    return std::make_unique<Boolleen>(*this);
}

std::unique_ptr<Valeur> Null::clone() const
{
    return std::make_unique<Null>(*this);
}
```

error :

```
invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘common::Boolleen’                          unique_ptr.h 857
```

**SECOND MINIMAL EXEMPLE WITH persistant problem** :

**Valeur.hh**

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
namespace common {

class Valeur {
public:
    virtual bool operator==(Valeur const& v) const =0;
};
class Boolleen : public Valeur {
private:
    bool _b;
public:
    Boolleen (bool b);
    bool operator==(Valeur const& v);

};

}
```

**Valeur.cpp**

```
#include "valeur.h"
using namespace common;

Boolleen::Boolleen(bool b): Valeur(), _b(b) {}

bool Boolleen::operator==(Valeur const& v) {
    return true;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "valeur.h"
int main()
{
    common::Boolleen b(true); // DOESN'T WORK ???
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't copy a `unique_ptr`  "as is" - If you use a class to carry it, you need to implement the copying yourself.

Comment: yes, i know but i don't see where i make a copy

Comment: It's too much code to dig into right now. Do you have more than one class carrying a `unique_ptr`? I see that you return `unique_ptr<...>` _plenty_. I don't know the purpose of this but could you have missed a `move`?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please ensure you include the [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can ensure we assist you as best as we can.

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo:

```
class Boolleen : public Valeur { //problem
    private:
        bool _b;
    public:
        Boolleen (bool const& b);
        std::unique_ptr<Valeur> clone () const override = 0;
        // TYPO Setting clone() to pure virtual makes Boolleen abstract
};
```

Just get rid of the `= 0` and it is fine.

Comment: yes thanks,  i sawing this error on my minimal example. but now I have corrected this on my original code it shows me the same error :(

Comment: Make sure that everything that is pure virtual in Valeur is implemented in Boolleen, and there are no other functions set to pure virtual.

Comment: I do not find. I posted a second minimal example in my first post where the problem is still persistent

Comment: In your 2nd example, you posted the header twice instead of CC file.

Comment: I updated the code, but I found the error : the signature of a pure virtual method was not correctly written in the Boolean class. This shows the importance of the override keyword ;)